# Realtek RTL8101 Wi-Fi services on Loki (elementary OS 0.4)

Tags: release-loki, wifi, networking, hardware

Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI EXPRESS FAST/GIGABIT Ethernet Controller
Laptop is Hp-r014-tx

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that your network card isn't detected, try installing the Realtek driver [from their website](http://www.realtek.com.tw/DOWNLOADS/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) ("LINUX driver"). If needed, there are install directions [at Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/470609/49899).

Answer (score 0):

You're correct I too use these drivers and on one of my HDD's it was out of date seeing it's my backup. On it I had an issue where I refused to detect, the other my main HDD all went smooth, I copied [the drivers](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=7&PFid=10&Level=3&Conn=2) over from the 2nd HDD and it started working just fine.